# Python run set.intersection with set of sets as input

Tags: python-2.7

I am working with biological datasets, straight from transcriptome (RNA) to finding certain protein sequences. I have a set of the protein names for each dataset, and want to find which are common to all datasets. Due to how the data is processed, I end up with a one variable that contains all the sub sets.
Due to how the `set.intersect()` command works, it requires at least 2 sets as input:

```
IDs = set.intersection(transc1 & trans2)
```

However I only have one input, `colA` which contains 30 sets of 80 to 100 entries. Here is what I have so far:

```
from glob import glob
for file in glob('*_query.tsv'): #input all 30 datasets, first column with protein IDs
  sources = file
  colnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 
  df = pandas.read_csv(sources, sep='\t', names=colnames) #colnames headers for df contruction
  colA = df.a.tolist() #turn column a, protein IDs, into list
  IDs = set(colA) #turn lists into sets
```

If I `print(colA)`, the output is something like this, with two unnamed elements as sets:

```
set(['ID2', 'ID8', 'ID35', 'ID77', 'ID78', 'ID199', 'ID211'])
set(['ID1', 'ID5', 'ID8', 'ID88', 'ID105', 'ID205'])
```

At this point I get stuck. I can't get `set.intersection()` working with the `IDs` set of sets. Also tried `pandas.merge(*IDs)` for which the syntax seemed to work, but the number of entries for comparison exceeded the maximum (12).

I wanted to use sets because unlike lists, it should be quick to find common IDs between all the datasets. If there is a better way, I am all for it.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `transc1 & trans2` is the same as `transc1.intersection(trans2)`. From your code, it's not so clear, what your data looks like. How do these 30 input sets look like (i see only 6 columns referenced by name)?

Comment: Hi dhke, columns b though to f become important much later on - for this part, only a is called.

column a, on each line, has an ID. That column is then turned into an individual set of IDs. This is done for each dataset (transcriptome), so there are 30 sets of IDs each from their own column a within `colA`. This is done at the same time, as the `glob('*_query.tsv')`  part does this simultaneously for all 30 source files.

So as it's written here, you'd end up with column a of 30 source files, as sets, within a set under the variable `colA`.

Comment: Ah! Can you fix your indentation, please? The for loop is easy to overlook and currently it's unclear where it terminates.

Comment: sure can dhke. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `set.intersection(*IDs)`, but I'm not sure if you are using the same name `IDs` for two different objects. In your code, it's the set of IDs from one dataset but your description seems to mention that it is a list of all the IDs from all datasets.

Comment: Tired `set.intersection(*IDs)`, doesn't work. Comes back with the following error: 
TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'str'

`colA = df.a.tolist()` turns all 30 column a 's into a list.
`IDs = set(colA)` then turns those 30 sub-lists into sub-sets.

Comment: As I said, there is still some discrepancy. According to you, `colA` is already a set (of strings) and there's nothing in your code that turns `IDs` into a set of sets (you would have to use `frozenset` for the inner sets to to create sets of sets, as sets are not hashable). So, please, post the actual, full code that you are currently using.